# Android: modifying an XML element in a timer

Tags: android, xml, textview, timertask

I am trying to have a counter (count seconds and minutes) and update it on the display every second.

I have this code in the `onCreate` of my class, which extends `Activity`:

```
timeOnCall = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
minutes = seconds = 0;
timeOnCall.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);

// Implements the timer
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        ++seconds;
        if (seconds == 60) {
            seconds = 0;
            ++minutes;
        }
        // Display the new time
        timeOnCall.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    }
}, 1000, 1000);
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

`android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException:` Only the original `thread` that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

I am not sure how to fix this as it's already in the `onCreate()` method. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a handler, something lite this:

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
final Runnable updateText = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        timeOnCall.setText(minutes + ":" + seconds);
    }
};
```

in onCreate you can then run:

```
onCreate(Bundle b) {
...
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            ++seconds;
            if (seconds == 60) {
                seconds = 0;
                ++minutes;
            }

            // Display the new time
        mHandler.post(updateText);
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your trying to change the textview from inside a different thread.  You can't do that.  You need to post a message back to the thread that owns the textview.

```
public void run()
```

This starts a new thread that is separate from what is running your UI.

Edit:  There are tons of examples online for the code you are looking for.  Just Google something like "Android thread message handler."

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure how to do that, do you have a tutorial or example for me please? That would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: So is it the "new TimerTask" which should be a new Thread that does the .setText() please?

Comment: I did put the whole code in a the run method of a new thread that I created. That still crashes.

Comment: More than likely you will want to leave control of the UI objects to the main thread.  Don't let the timer thread control them.  Threads are great for tasks like yours above.  You just need to get a message back to the main thread to update the textview.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete step-by-step of what you are trying to do and doing it without a background thread.  This is preferred over a timer because a timer uses a separate thread to do the update.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html